# Did Korben engage in a fight in The Fifth Element?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-fifth-element

In *The Fifth Element*, when Korben (Bruce Willis) takes the stone from Diva (opera performer), his shirt had sleeves. But right after when he comes out of the opera house, his sleeves are ripped off and got blood on them.

It might mean that he got engaged in a fight. However, there wasn't any scene depicting that.

Is there any plot inconsistency that wasn't accounted or was there a fight scene that didn't make it into the final cut?

Comment: Well spotted...

Comment: I thought he ripped off his sleeves to make a sling in which to carry the stones.

Comment: @Tim No, he used jacket for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no extra fight scene in the [**script**](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Fifth-Element,-The.html), Korben goes from having a single handgun to...

> Three Mangalores are suddenly blasted through the glass door leading to
>   the theater.  Korben bursts into the hall, two huge guns in his hands.

Consequently, a fight is implied...otherwise where did he get the big gun(s) from? He must have taken it from the three Mangalores in the opera house...these guys who come back in to investigate a noise....

[image]

then kills three more Mangalores with the big gun as he exits.

[image]